# Python index issue, looking for prettier code

Tags: python

my current code is like below, I'm using try and except to pass the exception from list indexing, length of "text" could be less than 3 sometimes. I'm looking for a prettier way. Please let me know your idea, thanks.

```
for item in items:
  text = item.splitlines()
  try:
    name = text[0]
  except:
    name = ""

  try:
    tag = text[1]
  except:
    tag = ""

  try:
    age = text[2]
  except:
    age = ""
```

Comment: use if statements to check the length of the list `if len(text) > 0: name=text[0]`

Comment: "Prettier" is opinion based. How are we supposed to know what you consider pretty code?

Comment: Or three newline characters to the string before splitting. Something like `name, tag, age = (item + '\n\n\n').splitlines()[:3]` would work, or `name, tag, age = (item.splitlines() + ['', '', ''])[:3]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
text = item.splitlines()
name, tag, age = (text + [""] * 3)[:3]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks prettier to me.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` has `izip_longest()`:

```
keys = ['name', 'tag', 'age']
name, tag, age = (item[1] for item in izip_longest(keys, text, fillvalue=""))
```

Arguably, this is a lot more useful handy when you want a `dict`:

```
dict(izip_longest(keys, text, fillvalue=""))
```

Comment: You could also do `item for _, item in izip_longest(...)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can't really decide which one is uglier, though.